# Is there versions history for the iOS app?

Tags: support, ios-app

Is there publicly available versions history for the iOS app?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the iTunes page for the Stack Exchange app, scroll down, click "Version History".

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

No such thing exists here on MSE as far as I know.

Since there is one single developer for the iOS app for long time now (Brian Nickel), you can just browse through [his answers on the tag, sorted by activity](//meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=user%3a235711%20%5bios-app%5d%20is%3aa%20) to get a good idea what has been changed or fixed over time.

You can also narrow it down to look for changes in specific version, e.g. [1.6.2.5](//meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A235711+%5Bios-app%5D+is%3Aa+%221.6.2.5%22).